# How to run scriptblock on Windows PowerShell on 64-bit machine

Tags: windows, powershell, 64-bit

I would like to run the script block to find the software available on a system.
Below are my code snippet.

```
$scriptBlock = {
    $key = Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' |
           Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -match 'Skype' };
    return $key
}

$installed64 = @(& "$env:SystemRoot\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command $scriptBlock)
```

When I executed the above command in the 64-bit machine I am getting an error as

```
& : The term 'C:\WINDOWS\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' is
not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:20
+ ... led64 = @(& "$env:SystemRoot\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powersh ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\WINDOWS\sysn...\powershell.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I would like run the command in "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" PowerShell.

How can I run the scriptblock?

Comment: `$installed64 = & $scriptBlock`?

Comment: Your command would only work from a 32-bit instance of PowerShell. Is that where you're running it from? If not, use @AnsgarWiechers' suggestion.

Comment: @ mklement0 i would like run the scriptblock in the  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM powershell

Comment: Why? That should not be required under any normal circumstances.

Comment: @surendra, as an aside: for @ notifications to be effective, there must be no space between the "@" and the user name. Please clarify in your question _why_ you would like to run with that identity, and how your current error message relates to that intent, notably: are you calling this from a 32-bit PowerShell instance?

Comment: @  mklement0   yes... my tool calls the 32 bit powershell instance to execute my script.  then sysnative giving the error